# Reading files in a .NET project

Tags: c#, .net, installation, windows-installer, web-applications

I have a C# .NET web project that I'm currently working on.  What I'm trying to do is read some files that I dropped into a dir which is at the same level as fileReader.cs which is attempting to read them.  On a normal desktop app the following would work:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(./myDir);
```

However because it's a web project the execution context is different, and I don't know how to access these files?

Eventually fileReader will be called in an installation routine.  I intend to override one of the Installer.cs' abstract methods so will this affect the execution context?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178116.aspx) to get the local path for the currently executing page.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Server.MapPath method whichs maps the specified relative or virtual path to the corresponding physical directory on the server.

```
Server.MapPath("mydir/file.some")
```

This returns: *C:\site\scripts\mydir\file.some*

Script also can call the MapPath with full virtual path:

```
Server.MapPath("/scripts/mydir/file.some")
```

Here is the [link to the MSDN documentation of MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e7ykf56.aspx).